# About machine epsilon in R

Tags: r

According to wikipedia, "Machine epsilon gives an upper bound on the relative error due to rounding in floating point arithmetic".

Thus, if I type (0.6-0.5) == 0.1 in R, I would expect the answer to be TRUE since (0.6-0.5) - 0.1 < 2^(-53) (machine epsilon in binary64). But the output gives FALSE. Why does this happen?

Comment: `all.equal(0.6-0.5,0.1)` is TRUE. This question is a duplicate. Looking for target.

Comment: You should read `help(".Machine")`.